# On Adding row in interactive grid apex 5, the sequence doesn't work and displays error that the field cant be empty

Tags: sequence, oracle-apex-5

I imported an application from  workspace 1 to workspace  2  together with its table data and definition, but the problem is that, on adding a record in interactive grid of the imported application in workspace 2, it displays error that the PK cant be NULL. I leave the PK field empty because i expect that the sequence will do that job the way it does in the same application of workspace 1. 
What is the reason that the same imported application is working a bit differently in a sense that sequence doesn't populate values itself.
What should be done to make the sequence work in the imported application in workspace 2.

[image: Application in second wrokspace (Interactive Grid)]

Comment: A sequence does not populate a column by itself, it needs to be used by something - could be a database trigger, or in Oracle 12C a column default can reference a sequence.  How does yours get used?

Comment: I dont know the mechanism behind the interactive grid region of the Apex 5. All we need to do after dragging the region to the page in designer view is that we write the SQL query that retrieves the records and there are some built in buttons such as add row which adds a record to the table. The code behind the button is not shown. In workspace 1, I just used to enter data with empty PK (MB No in the screenshot) and save it. The PK field used to get filled with the next sequence number by itself after saving. My point is why the same application in workspace 2 is behaving differently.

Comment: Maybe workspace 2 is on a different database or schema, and there is no database trigger in place?  Ask your teacher.

Comment: The schema is different but the database is same as i have imported that too. And regarding the database trigger, i didn't put in place any triggers in workspace 1 by myself. I mean I developed the application from scratch and didn't come across anything that required to have a trigger defined.And I guess triggers also get exported alongwith the application Dont they?

Comment: I am probably sounding a bit stupid. Sorry

Comment: Database triggers don't get exported with APEX applications, no.  Is it a database trigger (`create trigger xxx before insert ...`) that you had?  If so you need to recreate it in the new schema.  If it wasn't a database sequence, what was it?

Answer (score 1):

A sequence isn't just "known" to the Interactive grid. You have to specify what sequence to use.  In your Interactive Grid go to the column definition. Under the **"Default"** header change the **Type** to **"Sequence"**.  Put the name of your sequence in the Sequence Field:

[image: Default Sequence]

If the schema in workspace one is different then the schema of workspace two there could be a whole lot of reasons it isn't behaving the same. Check for differences in the schemas. Does the sequence exist in your new schema? If using the old schema is it as simple as do you need to preface your sequence with the schema name? Lots of reasons that could be, rule out the simple stuff first.